# Select the next line of the matched pattern in clob column using oracle regular expression

Tags: regex, oracle

I have a clob column "details" in table xxx. I want to  select the next line of the matched pattern using Regex.

Input Text (CLOB DATA) like below :( all placed in new line)

```
MODEL_DATA 1
TEST1:
NONE
TEST2:
NONE
INFO:
SERVICES,VALUED-YES
TYPE:
NONE
```

I tried to use INFO as pattern match string and retrieve the next line of the text . But could not able to do it by using Regular expression function . Please help me to resolve this

Output :

```
SERVICES,VALUES-YES
```

Comment: welcome to SO.  Please share your attempt to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the below to get the details

```
select replace(regexp_substr(details,'INFO:'||chr(10)||'.+'),'INFO:') 
from your_table;
```

You can also try the below to be operation system independent

```
select replace(regexp_substr(details,'INFO: 
 ('||chr(10)||'|'||chr(13)||chr(10)||').+'),'INFO:') 
from your_table;
```

Comment: This works for the published sample, but it may not work if the text comes from an operating system which uses different characters for line breaks.

Comment: I edited the file in Windows and it is still working not sure about Mac